# Should I use an enum argument to determine function?

Tags: c, enums

So basically I use enums to indicate the purpose of a function.

I have a function and I want it to behave differently in some cases but I want to specify it as a parameter, so that it is readable to other people. Is it okay to use enums in this way? Or am I supposed to do in a different way?

Example:

```
enum ShredType {
    maximum,
    minimum,
    average 
};
```

and function body:

```
void ShredDataToBarPlot(double* dataArray, int arraySize, int shredInterval,
    enum ShredType type)
{
    if(NULL != dataArray && arraySize > shredInterval)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<getSignalSize()/2;i+=shredInterval)
        {
            if(type == maximum)
            {
              do something
            }
            else if (type == average)
            {
            do something else
            }
           ...
```

And the function call example is:

```
ShredDataToBarPlot(someArray, someArraySize, someInterval, maximum);
```

You could translate my question to:
Is this a correct usage of enums? Am I not extending their original purpose? Will this way of parametrizing a function not confuse other people? 
I don't want to learn bad habits on my early journey of programming. If this question was inappropriate for stackoverflow please pm me where I can ask such questions.

Comment: We are not a tutoring/consulting service. Do you have a specific problem with your code? As a sidenote: consider using different functions or passing a function pointer. A single, complicated function to do different, unrelated things welcomes maintenance problems and is harder to debug.

Comment: Instead of `if` `else` you can go with `switch` `case`. I am just suggesting. Otherwise, it's perfectly okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a fine reason to use `enums`. The one thing I think would be done differently, is that rather than using a series of `if`, `else if`, `else` statements you use a `switch` statement like this:

```
switch(type)
  {
case maximum:
   ...
break;
case average:
   ...
break;
  }
```

Might also be worth changing the capitalisation of the `emum` values so they look less like variables too ie `Maximum`, `Average` etc...